# Number of ways of putting n balls in k boxes if boxes only fit n/2 balls

Tags: combinatorics

How can i find the unique ways of putting `N` balls in `K` boxes,considering that one box only fits `N/2` balls.Boxes can have 0 balls.
Test case
`N=4  K=3`

Possible combinations

```
2 2 0
2 0 2
0 2 2
2 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 1
```

Comment: Hint:  can you do the problem without the cap?  If so, then to conclude it helps to note that no unconstrained solution can violate the rule in more than one box...so now just study the solutions which do violate in exactly one box.

Comment: Note:  your header doesn't match the body of the question (in one you say $\frac k2$ in the other you say $\frac N2$).  Which did you intend?  (my prior comment assumed you meant $\frac N2$).  Also, you need to specify if the balls and or boxes are distinguishable.  I would guess that you mean that the balls are indistinguishable but the boxes can be distinguished (but that is just a guess).

Comment: Yes i meant n/2 balls sorry @lulu

Comment: That's fine, but you still need to clarify whether the boxes are distinguishable or not.  To be clear, if $N=4$ and $k=5$ are the two solutions $(2,2,0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,0,2,2)$ the same or are they different?  (I am assuming you want the balls to be indistinguishable but if I am wrong about that you should say).

Comment: @lulu nope they are different.

Comment: You mean my two solutions are different?  If so, you should edit your question to reflect that (it isn't obvious).  Or did you mean that "the balls are different"?  That is possible too, of course, though I'd say it was unusual.

Comment: @lulu i added a testcase hope that helps you

Comment: Yes, that makes it perfectly clear.  Thank you.  So it happens that the hint in my first comment made the right assumptions.  Can you proceed along those lines?

Comment: @lulu nope,unfortunately i didn't understand what you wanted to say

Comment: Ok.  Do you know about [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))?  That is a good way to get the unconstrained solution.

Comment: @lulu yes i know that solution,but i don't how to implement that on `n/2`

Comment: Ok.  So having the unconstrained solution, the only bad cases have more than $\frac N2$ in exactly one box.  There are $k$ ways to pick that one box and the bad box might have anywhere from $\lfloor \frac N2\rfloor+1$ to $N$ balls in it.  For each case, use Stars and Bars to count the ways to put the remaining balls in the remaining boxes and sum over the cases.

Comment: Once again:  I am relying on the fact that no unconstrained solution can have more than one bad box (as that would give us more than $N$ balls).  This method gets a lot worse if you replace the cap of $\frac N2$ with $\frac N{10}$ or something like that.

Comment: @lulu thank you so much!